# Best way to run a command using either a file as input or stdin

Tags: bash, awk

I am writing a script to format a file such that each column has a width of the length of its longest record+1. The script works fine run as `./auto_format file` and `cat file | ./auto_format`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# auto_format file 

case $# in
  1)
    file="$1"
    ;;
  0)
    file=$(mktemp || echo "failed, exiting..." 1>&2; exit 1)
    cat > $file <&0
    ;;
  *)
    echo "usage: auto_format [file]" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

awk ' 
NR==FNR {
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
  if (length($i) > max[i]) max[i]=length($i);
  }
}
NR!=FNR {
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
  printf "%-*s", max[i]+1, $i 
}
printf "\n"
  }
  ' "$file" "$file"
```

However, I do not like the use of a temporary file when receiving input from STDIN, and was wondering if I could pass on a copy of input to awk so I don't have to use a temp file. Something like: awk [script] STDIN COPY_STDIN

Comment: Feel free to take a look at `column -t filename`.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks! However, I don't think column is a command on AIX. Also, awk will allow greater flexibility should I feel the need to tweak things like the number of delimeters to output, IFS, OFS, etc. Maybe the temp file is the best option? I just thought there would be a more elegant solution. Thanks! (and before you ask, I realise mktemp is not on POSIX!) just can't test on the working machine atm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're making this harder than it has to be. Awk is perfectly capable of handling piped stdin or a file and you dont need a tmp file unless your input is huge which it sounds like it's not from your comments::

```
$ cat tst.sh
awk '
{ 
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if (length($i) > max[i]) max[i]=length($i);
    }
    line[NR] = $0
}
END {
    for (nr=1; nr<=NR; nr++) {
        nf = split(line[nr],flds)
        for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
            printf "%-*s", max[i]+1, flds[i]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
' "$@"
```

.

```
$ cat file
abc de fghi
abcde f ghiklm
$ 
$ ./tst.sh file
abc   de fghi   
abcde f  ghiklm 
$ 
$ cat file | ./tst.sh
abc   de fghi   
abcde f  ghiklm
```

Comment: Nice! This method should be faster and allows for more than one file argument. I will mark this as the answer now. The other answer was also very helpful.

Comment: Also handles NULs, and will work regardless of shell or OS implementation (AFAIK).

Answer (score 2):

One great way to handle this is to redirect your stdin from a file if that file is provided:

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then exec <"$1"; fi
```

This will open the file in your first argument, replacing stdin, if and only if a filename is provided.

---

That said, your specific case here is trickier, and you *do* need to capture content, since you want to return the user's input twice. However, you don't necessarily need to capture out to a file -- capturing to a variable, and playing that variable back twice, will do. If your content doesn't contain NULs, that's as simple as the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^- this will not work with /bin/sh

if [ -n "$1" ]; then exec <"$1"; fi

IFS= read -r -d '' content
awk ... <(printf '%s' "$content") <(printf '%s' "$content")
```

If your content *does* contain NULs, a solution is still possible by storing content in an array rather than a scalar variable (since POSIX shells use C-style NUL-terminated strings, a scalar can't contain a NUL -- but the divisions between array entries can represent the places where NULs would be), but the corner cases get a bit hairy; frankly, it's easier to use a temporary file (or a language like Python that uses Pascal strings, which aren't NUL-delimited) at that point.

Comment: Thanks so very much, your answer is brilliant. That if statement will simplify some of my scripts so I no longer have to do `case #?` gymnastics :) As far as I know, none of my content should contain NULs. When should I worry about NUL chacters? Larger character sets?

Comment: NULs are a concern with almost all binary files -- executables, compressed content, images -- and content intended to be unambiguously parsed as a sequence of C strings (for instance, the output of `find -print0` is NUL-delimited because that's the safest way to represent a sequence of filenames -- no kinds of escaping or other encoding are needed to distinguish between control characters within the names and control characters intended to separate the names).

Comment: To be fair, by the way -- this approach is somewhat inefficient; passing the original filename when a filename is available will have better performance. That said, for small inputs that may not matter.

Comment: Should be fine then! Good to know print0 outputs NULs, seems like it breaks `columnt -t` as well. Thanks again, have a great day